# Kafka Streams - can I use in production

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I wonder if I can use Kafka Streams in production.

Is it really open source? Or Should we buy some license?

I am looking up documentation [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) and [Licence FAQs](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq/) but it isn't clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Streams is Apache 2.0 Licensed, not sure why you're looking at Confluent License pages

Its source code exists with the Kafka Broker, JVM clients, and Kafka Connect sources